Choosing two numbers in $(0, 1)$, what's the probability that their sum is smaller than $7/5$?
My thought process is as follows:
Choosing two numbers $a$ and $b$ in $(0, 1)$, then we need $a + b < 7/5$. So we have $b < -a + 7/5$. Next, we basically need to calculate the area below the line $b = -a + 7/5$ and its intersection with the square $(0,0),(0, 1), (1,0), (1,1)$.
I think the area is $1\times1 - 2/5\times2/5\times1/2 = 23/25$.
But the answer to the problem shows $41/50$, and I have no idea which steps went wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

I think your thought process is perfect but you failed in the execution. The area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{3}{5}$ and now we subtract this from the area of a unit square to obtain the required answer.

Lol that was awkward. The side of the triangle is actually $1 - 2/5$. Thanks for pointing it out this fast!
